# SOAP Conversion for GraphQL

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, soap, graphql

Can [GraphQL](http://graphql.org) communicate with a SOAP service directly as a data source, or does a SOAP-to-REST conversion layer need to be built? If so, what technology (language, framework, OS, etc.) could/should be used to translate SOAP messages for the GraphQL layer?

Right now, I'm still learning about GraphQL, and am considering building a SOAP-to-Nodejs conversion layer using [LoopBack](https://loopback.io). I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate approach to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL is completely agnostic to the layers beneath it. If you have an existing SOAP infrastructure, it's certainly possible to link the two together, but support for doing so isn't built-in in any meaningful sense.

Given that SOAP is basically RPC, i'm not sure if i'd bother with an automatic conversion layer, just map the field resolvers to the appropriate SOAP method calls. Behind-the-scenes, GraphQL servers map onto RPC very cleanly.